# conan create cannot find dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have a project that uses a `conanfile.py` to both manage its dependencies and provide a recipe for its own package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Conan file for KVTest, a library used to support the development of tests.

To install dependencies view https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/vs2017_cmake.html
"""

from conans import ConanFile, CMake


class KVTestConan(ConanFile):
    name = "kvtest"
    version = "0.1.0.0"
    description = "Kiwi Test Support library"
    topics = ("kv", "kvtest", "C++")
    settings = "os", "arch", "compiler", "build_type"
    options = {"shared": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False}
    generators = "cmake_find_package"
    exports_sources = ["src/*", "include/*", "cmake/*", "CMakeLists.txt", "Config.hpp.in"]

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("gtest/1.8.1@bincrafters/stable")
        self.requires("boost/1.70.0@conan/stable")

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        # Let's skip tests since the final package doesn't need them
        cmake.configure(build_folder="build/")
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="src")
        self.copy("*.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["kvtest"]
```

In development I navigate to the project directory and do `conan install . kvtest/0.1.0.0@kiwi/testing -if="<path to Visual studio build folder>`, all dependencies are installed and the project builds successfully in Visual Studio.

My problem is that when I try to create a package for that project it cannot find its dependencies. My `CMakeLists.txt` has all the required `find_package()` calls:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
find_package(gtest REQUIRED)
find_package(boost REQUIRED)
```

But when I try to create the package it can't find any dependencies:

```
kvtest/0.1.0.0@kiwi/testing: Calling build()
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27032.1
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- clang-format found: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-format.exe
-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
-- Boost version: 1.70.0
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:50 (add_library):
  Target "kvtest" links to target "gtest::gtest" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:50 (add_library):
  Target "kvtest" links to target "boost::boost" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I use this in other packages so I'm at a loss at to what be causing this now.

Answer (score 0):

The generator `cmake_find_package` is not a replacement for the original `FindGTest.cmake` provided by the author. Read the references below.

You are trying to use specific variables provided by the author, as `GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY`, which are not available in `cmake_find_package` generator, it won't work.

The best generators you can use for your case is `cmake_find_package` for Boost, and `cmake_paths` for GTest. The GTest Conan package contains the original FindGTest and FindGMock files, which allow you finding what you want. Of course, you will need to change the module name from `find_package(gtest)` to `find_package(GTest)` in your cmake file.

> CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:50 (add_library):
>     Target "kvtest" links to target "boost::boost" but the target was not
>     found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
>     an ALIAS target is missing?

Seems like your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is not okay, otherwise Boost would be found with no problem.

If you want learn more about CMake generators, you can read the blog post about  [transparent cmake integration](https://blog.conan.io/2018/06/11/Transparent-CMake-Integration.html).

You can read more on [cmake_find_package reference](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html).

Comment: Can I ask you to please review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

So this is caused by the fact that I enforce out of source builds on CMake.

All my root CMakeLists.txt (I have several projects) have the following lines:

```
if (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there. You may need to remove CMakeCache.txt.")
endif (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

which means that in the build directory I need to 1) create the build folder and then 2) copy all Find*.cmake files into it:

```
path = os.path.normpath(self.source_folder)
build = os.path.join(path, "build/")
os.mkdir(build)
with os.scandir(path) as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        if entry.is_file() and fnmatch.fnmatch(entry.name, "Find*.cmake"):
            shutil.copy2(entry.path, build)
```

After this the build finishes correctly.

Comment: What about GTest defines? `GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY` won't be available. Your solution only solves `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`